# spring-webflow - maven problem

Tags: maven-3, spring-webflow-2

I am trying to build a simple webapp that uses spring webflow. I am having trouble retrieving the webflow dependency (I'm using maven 3).

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I run a mvn clean install -X (from the command line), I get the following...

> Failed to execute goal on project blah-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project cnm3:blah-webapp:war:1
>   .0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework.webflow:spring-webflow:jar:2.3.0-RELEASE in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

I can see that the jars are available  at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/webflow/spring-webflow/

anyone come across this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct version value is 2.3.0.RELEASE

Comment: I was staring at that version for so long and didn't see it... (I suppose I am used to typing **-SNAPSHOT** and not *.SNAPSHOT*)

Comment: Sorry that I had to state the obvious ;-) But I know the feeling, kind of like this inception sketch, trying to look too deep: http://static.funnyjunk.com/pictures/6dc54c55_3173_50a6.jpg